# Fitting a quadratic using regression when the y-intercept needs to be 0

Tags: polynomials, linear-regression

I'm trying to fit a quadratic $a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2$ by Polynomial Regression:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
n &  \Sigma x_i  & \Sigma x_i\\
\Sigma x_i &  \Sigma x_i^2  & \Sigma x_i^3\\
\Sigma x_i^2 &  \Sigma x_i^3  & \Sigma x_i^4\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_0\\
a_1\\
a_2\\
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\Sigma y_i\\
\Sigma x_iy_i\\
\Sigma x_i^2y_i\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
by Gaussian Elimination on the augmented matrix:
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
n &  \Sigma x_i  & \Sigma x_i & \Sigma y_i\\
\Sigma x_i &  \Sigma x_i^2  & \Sigma x_i^3 & \Sigma x_iy_i\\
\Sigma x_i^2 &  \Sigma x_i^3  & \Sigma x_i^4 & \Sigma x_i^2y_i\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

I'm not a matrix whizz, so how do I solve this using the same method when I know I want the y-intercept of the curve, $a0$, to be 0?

Comment: Regarding some of your comments below, see http://mathoverflow.net/help/on-topic -- the StackExchange tag line is not entirely accurate, and MathOverflow actually predates MathStackExchange which is the more appropriate site for questions like this

Comment: @YemonChoi Why am I not able to delete my answer? Is it because the question is closed, or because the answer is accepted?

Comment: @M.Vinay I'm not sure - it could be either or both of those reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want $a_0$ to be $0$, then the curve you are trying to fit has equation $y = a_1 x + a_2 x^2$. If you derive the normal equations starting from this equation, you get

$a_1 \sum x_i^2 + a_2 \sum x_i^3 = \sum x_i y_i\\
a_1 \sum x_i^3 + a_2 \sum x_i^3 = \sum x_i^2 y_i$

Or

$\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
\sum x_i^2 & \sum x_i^3 & \sum x_i y_i\\
\sum x_i^3 & \sum x_i^4 & \sum x_i^2 y_i
\end{array}\right]$

**Derivation of Normal Equations**
$y = a_1 x + a_2 x^2$

The error $\epsilon_i$ in the $i$<sup>th</sup> term is the difference between the predicted value $y(x_i)$ and the observed value $y_i$:
$\epsilon_i = y(x_i) - y_i = a_1 x_i + a_2 x_i^2 - y_i$

The total error is the sum of squares of these errors:
$E = \displaystyle\sum_i \epsilon_i^2 = \displaystyle\sum_i(a_1x_i + a_2x_i^2 - y_i)^2$

To find the values of the parameters $a_1$ and $a_2$ that minimize the total error, let $\dfrac{\partial E}{\partial a_1} = \dfrac{\partial E}{\partial a_2} = 0$:

$
\dfrac{\partial E}{\partial a_1} = \sum 2x_i(a_1 x_i + a_2 x_i^2 - y_i) = 0 \Rightarrow a_1 \sum x_i^2 + a_2 \sum x_i^3 = \sum x_i y_i\\
\dfrac{\partial E}{\partial a_2} = \sum 2x_i^2(a_1 x_i + a_2 x_i^2 - y_i) = 0 \Rightarrow a_1 \sum x_i^3 + a_2 \sum x_i^4 = \sum x_i^2 y_i\\
$

Comment: This website is for questions about math research. Please don't answer questions that don't belong here.

Comment: @EdKing He's right, actually: "MathOverflow's primary goal is for users to ask and answer **research level math questions**". I knew this, but still answered as I didn't see any comments or downvotes on the question. You should have asked this on Mathematics StackExchange, though.